# How to port CPLEX linear optimization from Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, cplex

I am trying to port an application from Matlab to C++. This application contains a linear optimization problem of the form:

> min. *F* * x
>
> s.t. **A** * x < *Rhs*
>
> s.t. *Lb* <= x <= *Ub*

which needs to be solved.

The matlab API of CPLEX supports writing all coefficients as vectors (*F*, *Rhs*, *Lb*, and *Ub*) or matrices (**A**) respectively. The C++ interface however does not. Instead the problem needs to be constructed by row or by column.

Here I am stuck since I can't seem to geht the same result in Matlab and C++ even for a small toy problem.

```Matlab
t_v_l = [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]';
t_v_m = [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]';
t_v_r = [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1]';

t_h_o = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]';
t_h_m = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]';
t_h_u = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]';

target = [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0];

dict = [t_v_l, t_v_m, t_v_r, t_h_o, t_h_m, t_h_u];

M = size(dict, 1);
N = size(dict, 2);

F = zeros(N + M, 1);
F(N + 1 : N + M) = ones(M,1); 

Lb = sparse(zeros(N + M, 1));
Lb(N + 1 : N + M) = 0;

Ub = ones(N + M, 1);
Ub(N + 1 : N + M) = 999;

Rhs = zeros(2 * M, 1);
Rhs(    1 :     M) = -target;
Rhs(M + 1 : 2 * M) =  target;

Lhs = -999 * ones(2 * M, 1);

A = zeros(2 * M, N + M);
A(    1 :     M,     1 : N    ) = -dict;
A(M + 1 : 2 * M,     1 : N    ) =  dict;
A(    1 :     M, N + 1 : N + M) = -eye(M);
A(M + 1 : 2 * M, N + 1 : N + M) = -eye(M);

plex = Cplex('myModel');

plex.addCols(F, [], Lb, Ub);
plex.addRows(Lhs, A, Rhs);
            
plex.writeModel('ex.lp'); % Optional

plex.solve();

X = plex.Solution.x;

fprintf("Solution:\n")
disp(X');
```

Conceptually I am trying to reconstruct a binary target vector from different binary templates. The first 6 entries in the solution show which templates have to be chosen (in this case template 2 and 5). The remaining entries correspond to slack variables where the reconstruction is not entirely accurate due to overlap or noise in the target. The code above works and gives me the correct result.

However, when I try to follow the examples (like Ilodiet.cpp) to produce the same results in the Concert API the optimization does not work anymore.

```
#ifndef IL_STD
#define IL_STD
#endif
#include <cstring>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <vector>
ILOSTLBEGIN

void main()
{
    // Input Data
    std::vector<vector<float>> dict =
    {
        { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    std::vector<float> target =
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 };

    const int M = target.size();
    const int N = dict.size();

    // Build Matrix A
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> A;
    for(int r = 0; r < M; ++r)
    {
        std::vector<float> row(N + M, 0);
        for(int c = 0; c < N; ++c)
        {
            row[c] = -dict[c][r];
        }
        row[N + r] = -1;
        A.push_back(row);
    }

    for (int r = M; r < 2 * M; ++r)
    {
        std::vector<float> row(N + M, 0);
        for (int c = 0; c < N; ++c)
        {
            row[c] = dict[c][r - M];
        }
        row[N + r - M] = -1;
        A.push_back(row);
    }

    // Build Model
    IloEnv env;
    IloModel mod(env);

    IloNumArray F(env, N + M);
    IloNumArray Lb(env, N + M);
    IloNumArray Ub(env, N + M);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        F[i] = 0.f;

        Lb[i] = 0.f;
        Ub[i] = 1.f;
    }

    for (int i = N; i < N + M; ++i)
    {
        Lb[i] = 0.f;
        Ub[i] = 999.f;// IloInfinity;

        F[i] = 1.f;
    }

    IloNumArray Rhs(env, 2 * M);
    IloNumArray Lhs(env, 2 * M);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        Rhs[i] = -target[i];
        Lhs[i] = -999.f;// -IloInfinity;

        Rhs[M + i] = target[i];
        Lhs[M + i] = -999.f;// -IloInfinity;
    }

    IloNumVarArray x(env, Lb, Ub, ILOFLOAT);

    IloObjective minimize = IloMinimize(env, IloScalProd(x, F));
    mod.add(IloExtractable(minimize));

    for (int r = 0; r < A.size(); ++r) 
    {
        IloExpr expr(env);
        for (int c = 0; c < A[r].size(); ++c) {
            expr += F[c] * A[r][c];
        }
        mod.add(expr <= Rhs[r]);
        expr.end();
    }

    IloCplex cplex(mod);
    cplex.exportModel("ex.lp");
    cplex.solve();
    
    std::cout << "Solution status = " << cplex.getStatus() << endl;
    std::cout << "Cost = " << cplex.getObjValue() << endl;

    std::vector<int> ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        try 
        {
            std::cout << "Template i: " << cplex.getValue(x[i]) << std::endl;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout << "Template i: 0 (optimized away)" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = N; i < N + M; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << "Slack i: " << cplex.getValue(x[i]) << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Slack i: 0 (optimized away)" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    env.end();
}
```

The output tells me that the presolver eliminated all rows and columns and my solution is empty. The exported problem files also look completely different.
If I take a look at the individual arrays however, they look exactly the same. So I guess I am doing something wrong while passing my information to the Concert API.

Where is my mistake? Any help is appreciated!

---

The code for printing the variables (since IloArrays are hard to look at in the debugger) in Matlab:

```
fprintf("F:\n");
disp(F');

fprintf("Lb:\n");
disp(Lb');

fprintf("Ub:\n");
disp(Ub');

fprintf("Lhs:\n");
disp(Lhs');

fprintf("Rhs:\n");
disp(Rhs');

fprintf("A:\n");
disp(A);
```

And in C++:

```
std::cout << "F:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N + M; ++i)
{
    std::cout << F[i] << ", ";
}

std::cout << "\n\nLb:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N + M; ++i)
{
    std::cout << Lb[i] << ", ";
}

std::cout << "\n\nUb:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N + M; ++i)
{
    std::cout << Ub[i] << ", ";
}

std::cout << "\n\nLhs:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * M; ++i)
{
    std::cout << Lhs[i] << ", ";
}

std::cout << "\n\nRhs:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * M; ++i)
{
    std::cout << Rhs[i] << ", ";
}

std::cout << "\n\nA:" << std::endl;
for (int r = 0; r < 2 * M; ++r)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < N + M; ++c)
    {
        std::cout.width(2);
        std::cout.fill(' ');
        std::cout << A[r][c] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of C++ code here. Rather than write your whole program and then try to debug it, I'd recommend starting with a very simple model and then building it up piece by piece. Comparing the LP files as you build it up should give you a good idea if you're doing things right. At a glance, one problem is the following: `expr += F[c] * A[r][c];`. I believe you mean to use `expr += x[c] * A[r][c];` (otherwise, you're just multiplying two scalars).

Comment: @rkersh Thank you very much. That was indeed the cause of CPLEX telling me that it removed all rows and columns. 
The only thing is, that the model above is already very simple compared to the ones I really intend to use. **A** originally has several million entries all either 0 or 1. I originally tried to compare the exported models for differences but even with your fix the exported models look very different even though the result is the same...

Comment: My point was that you should start by creating an empty model and exporting it to LP format. Then, try adding variables only (giving them names is a good idea as it helps with debugging). Make sure that when you export it to LP format, the variable bounds are correct, and that the objective is correct. Then (and only then), add a single constraint. Look at the LP file and make sure it is correct. Add all constraints that are similar to the first constraint. And, so on. In this way, you build the model up one step at a time, and if you run into a problem you know exactly where it is.

Comment: When `IloCplex cplex(mod);` gets executed, the model is [extracted](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/Cpp/extract_model.html). This extraction process is unique to the object oriented Concert APIs (i.e., C++, Java, and .NET). It's not uncommon for models to look slightly different when using the C++ Concert API and comparing with a different API (e.g., MATLAB).